# how to redirect to an external URL using POST in grails

Tags: url, grails, post, redirect, parameters

I am integrating my website with payment gateway...I want to take some parameters from the user and add some parameters from my side , and then send data to the payment gateway. But the problem is I can only send the data from server side using redirect using a GET but not POST, the payment gateway expects the data in the post form as data contains sensitive information...So how can I pass the data to payment gateway through POST??

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect POST request, all redirections are new GET request, it's from specification.

Btw, you can add this parameters on client side, before sending to payment gateway. By using ajax for example. Or by making an extra page, with a form, that will be autosubmitted to payment gateway

Answer (score 1):

The two steps you need are:
First while making ajax call add parameters from user in client side.
Second add your required parameters on server-side. After that you can **forward** the details to your gateway.

```
def addYourParameters()
{
// did required operation here
forward controller:'gateway', action:'yourAction', params: [required Map]
}
```