# redirect with POST request

Tags: grails, redirect, post, get

I am using `redirect` like this:

```
redirect action:"action2",params:params
```

The form that is submitted to this code has **POST** request method, but when redirecting the request is being changed to **GET** *( I verified this using chrome developer tool)*, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to redirect to an external URL using POST in grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820797/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-using-post-in-grails)

Comment: if the incoming request is a post, you can try to do a 307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect support only get. For reference you can read same thread on following link.
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Does-redirect-have-a-quot-method-quot-arg-td1344221.html