# How to redirect one action to another with post request method

Tags: grails

Note: Second action only allows POST method. we can not hit that action by the user.

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST",booked:"POST"]

def save()
{
// did save operation here
redirect action:'booked'
}

def booked()
{
//did the operation related with this
render view :'payment'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820797/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-using-post-in-grails

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try forward

```
def save()
{// did save operation here
forward action:'booked'
}

def booked()
{
//did the operation related with this
render view :'payment'
}
```

All the parameters passed to **save** will directly get passed to **booked** method. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this as below by directly calling the method within save method

```
def save(){
booked()
}
```